# Typescript dom events type?

Tags: typescript

something like

```
type event="scroll"|"click"|"resize" ........ // and so on
```

could not find any. 
there is such a type?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/eac073894b172ec719ca7f28b0b94fc6e6e7d4cf/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L5671 ?

Comment: @zerkms no, i need literally the string types and not the entire interface - how can I do this?

Comment: `type event = keyof GlobalEventHandlersEventMap;`?

Comment: This really isn't a bad question because I don't know if the type is all that discoverable unless you're familiar with the Syntax for mapped types

Comment: @AluanHaddad agree, +1d to recover the status-quo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a union of literal types with the event names use the `keyof` operator:

```
type event = keyof GlobalEventHandlersEventMap;
```

References:

- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types
- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/eac073894b172ec719ca7f28b0b94fc6e6e7d4cf/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L5671